# Denies Access to AWS s3 Based on the Source URL or sourcedomain?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-bigquery, amazon-iam, aws-security-group

I blocked public access to my s3 bucket, but I wanted to allow the bigquery connection using the bigquery transfer service.

I saw the options to deny access using IP address, but since google doesn't have the public IP address, I don't know how to solve this issue.
Any experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deny access based on IP address. It's much easier to create an IAM user, attach S3ReadOnly policy, generate the access keys, and let bigquery to use the access keys to get data from S3. Restrict access based on IAM is better than the IP address approach.

Comment: currently, i have iam user with policy s3 read only, however, there's additional restriction  or policy that doesn't allow access outside our network. That's why I would need to know if i can whitelist bigquery using the sourceURL or sourceDomain, since i don't have info about google's range of IP addresses.

Comment: @Justin What do you mean by "additional restriction or policy that doesn't allow access outside our network"? Is this part of a Bucket Policy? Or is it part of the IAM User? Where is this restriction defined?

Comment: it's a policy attached to the IAM user as part of the security that does not allow any access outside our network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bucket policy for providing access. Refer to this article - https://medium.com/@Keithweaver_/only-allowing-access-to-your-s3-bucket-via-your-website-5ca5c8546152

Hope it helps.